# Javascript: Adding Field Totals

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add multiple numerical fields together and having the total of those fields in a separate field. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please consider updating your question to include an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the code you have tried so far. Also, please have another read through the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) that you were introduced to before you asked this question. In it's current form, this question is likely to be [closed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions).

Comment: Please provide your code, so we can come up with a solution. It will also help if you share what you have already tried, so we can show you where you went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear, but I make a demo to calculate sum of item you can reference

```
function total(){
   const items = document.querySelectorAll('.item');
   let total= 0;
   items.forEach(p => total+=parseFloat(p.value));
   document.getElementById('total').value = total;
}
```

```js
function total(){
const items = document.querySelectorAll('.item');
let total= 0;
items.forEach(p => total+=parseFloat(p.value));
document.getElementById('total').value = total;
}
```

```html
<input class='item' type='text' /><br>
<input class='item' type='text' /><br>
<input class='item' type='text' /><br>
<input class='item' type='text' /><br>
<input type='button' value='Calculate' onclick='total()' /><br>
<input type='text' id='total' />
```